# css nth-child: borders not displaying properly in chrome only

Tags: html, css

I have a Volusion e-commerce website that locks the inner HTML for my category pages. Using only the classes provided, I am attempting to add a top and bottom border to my table cell product listings on category pages. For some reason, and it's only in Chrome, the border spans across the entire table row, when it should not.

I am using the following css:

```
table.v65-productDisplay > tbody > tr > td > table.v65-productDisplay > tbody > tr:nth-child(5n+1) > td[width="33%"] {border-top:1px solid #D6D5D5;}
table.v65-productDisplay > tbody > tr > td > table.v65-productDisplay > tbody > tr:nth-child(5n+4) > td[width="33%"] {border-bottom:1px solid #D6D5D5;}
```

When I inspect the table cells that are spacers, and should not have a border, the element's css is showing that it does not have one. The only thing I can conclude is that somehow in chrome, a table cell is spanning across the entire row, causing one css border call to span the entire width of the table row.

I've tried just about everything I can think of, and I need a new pair of eyes on the problem. You can view this in action on my website: 
http://www.yandasmusic.com/Portable-Keyboards-s/2119.htm

Comment: It looks like it's the `table { border-collapse: collapse; }` style that's doing it.  Try playing around with that.

Comment: Also, for some reason, when you remove every 5th `tr` (the vertical spacers), the borders go away (but the spacing too, obviously...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

to:

```
table { border-collapse: initial; }
```

Comment: I think you mean either initial or separate, not inherit, because it seems pointless to inherit a property from a parent element where the property likely doesn't apply (or rather, it seems like a strange and unorthodox way to obtain the initial value).

Comment: Thanks guys. This did work. Just to spare myself some agony, what is going on this this css value? I've never used it before.

Comment: @AlexRitter: Possibly this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=356132